# widget test on FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, testing

im trying to simulate de data flow on a Stream Builder.

but i cant continue beyond: snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
only pass to the circularProgressIndicator that come next of ConnectionState.waiting

i dont know how to simulate the values to pass to other condition that i`ve on Stream.

```
this is the code i want to simulate 

class LoadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoadingPage> createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}

class _LoadingPageState extends State<LoadingPage> {
  late GeolocatorService geolocatorService;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    geolocatorService = Provider.of<GeolocatorService>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: geolocatorService.loadingData,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print('STREAM LOADING PAGE');
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          print('STREAM WAINTING');

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

//HOW TO SIMULATE THIS CONDITION????

        } else if (snapshot.data! && geolocatorService.isAllGranted) {
          print('STREAM SNAPSHOT');
          return const NewsDesignPage();
        } else {
          print('STREAM GPSACCESS');

          return const GpsAccessScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    geolocatorService.loadingData;
    super.dispose();
  }
}


this is what im tried:

  testWidgets('page flow with data ', (teste) async {
      final streamController = StreamController<bool>();
      final geolocator = GeolocatorService();

      await teste.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<GeolocatorService>(
              create: (context) => GeolocatorService()),
          // StreamProvider<bool>(
          //     create: (context) => Stream<bool>.fromIterable([true, false]),
          //     initialData: true)
          // StreamProvider<bool>.value(
          //     value: streamController.stream, initialData: true)
        ],
        child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const MaterialApp(
            home: LoadingPage(),
          );
        }),
      ));
      // streamController.add(true);

      await teste.pump();

      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);

      streamController.add(true);
      geolocator.gpsEnabled = true;
      geolocator.isPermissionGranted = true;

      await teste.pump();

      // expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);

      expect(find.byWidget(NewsDesignPage()), findsOneWidget);

      // expect(find.byWidget(const GpsAccessScreen()), findsNothing);
    });
```